# SQLAlchemy many-to-many association class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following two classes (simplified):

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "AppUser"
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Task"
    task_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I want to join them with a many-to-many association, but store an additional column besides the primary keys:

```
class Solved(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Solved"
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("AppUser.user_id"), primary_key=True)
    task_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Task.task_id"), primary_key=True)
    solved_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

I've chosen the class over the table because the SQLAlchemy documentation recommends using a class if I have to store additional columns.

My problem is that I can't "join" them.
I tried the following:

**Adding the references directly to the Association table:**

```
task = db.relationship("Task", backref="users")
user = db.relationship("AppUser", backref="tasks")
```

**Adding a reference to the User and task class:**

```
class User:
    [...]
    tasks = db.relationship("Solved", backref="users")

class Task:
    [...]
    users = db.relationship("Solved", backref="tasks")
```

Neither of them work.
To my surprise it work if I change the Solved class to an db.Table object.
I want to try the association class because I work with subqueries which reference Solved but don't accept an db.Table object.

What I want to do is adding "solved" tasks to the list:

```
u = User.query.get([...])
t = Task.query.get([...])
u.tasks.append(t)
db.session.add(u)
db.session.commit()
```

Edit:

When I check if an element is already "Solved":

```
# My models have name fields
u.tasks.filter_by(name="abc")
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: '_AssociationList' object has no attribute 'filter_by'
```

When I append a new element to the list:

```
u.tasks.append(t)
db.session.add(u) # These two steps work
db.session.commit() # Error

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: relationship 'user' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>)
```

Like mentioned above, it worked with a simple db.Table association, but not with an association class.

I also tried an association proxy like [here (SQLAlchemy docs)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects) but I get the same errors as above.

Comment: *What* exactly does not work? Code fails when you define relationship? Or some specific query? Can you provide the code of what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.
I mostly copied the [association proxy tutorial from the official doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html)
Here are some pitfalls and tips for other people who struggle:

- Write your association class after the classes you want to join.
  (Obvious for most of us, but it doesn't hurt to check)
- Add an `__init__` function to your association class!
- Double check your backrefs, class and table names.
  I've myself not looked through when to use which keyword, but most of the time there is your mistake.